# single front end to manage multiple websites having different databases

Tags: php, mysql

At present i have multiple front-ends (in PHP) connected with different databases (in Mysql) for each client. While the front end application is same for each client, I have to maintain multiple front-end applications .  Any change in one program I have to copy it in all websites.

How can I access the different websites from single front-end based on database connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use softlink for your code or you can use version control (git or svn) and update your code via version control.

There is no other way you can manage 3 websites (same code folder) via single U/I